# Chakra UI Table is it possible for a chakra UI component to have overflow x to have responsiveness?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chakra-ui

I have a Chakra UI Table that I want to have an overflow x when the whole table doesnt fit the screen anymore, can't seem to figure out how to put scroll left to right.

```
<Table my={{ base: '1rem' }}>
  <Thead>
    <Tr>
      <Th>Question</Th>
      <Th>Answer</Th>
      <Th>Action</Th>
    </Tr>
  </Thead>
  <Tbody>
    {faqs.map(faq => (
      <Tr key={faq._id}>
        <Td>{faq.question}</Td>
        <Td>{faq.answer}</Td>
        <Td width="15%">
          <ButtonGroup spacing="3">
            <Button
              colorScheme="blue"
              onClick={() => modalOnOpenHandler(faq._id)}
            >
              <EditIcon />
            </Button>
            <Button
              colorScheme="red"
              onClick={() => idDialogHandler(faq._id)}
            >
              <DeleteIcon />
            </Button>
          </ButtonGroup>
        </Td>
      </Tr>
```

The problem is that I have a flex parent for the sidebar menu and the content component that is why the scroll can't detect that it needs to be scrolled.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the Table element with a Box, and use the `overflowX` property of the Box.

```html
<Box overflowX="scroll">
  <Table>
  </Table>
</Box>
```

Note: `overflowX` on the Table itself didn't work for me.

I just ran into this myself, and found your question. It doesn't seem to be too documented on the [Style Props](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/styled-system/style-props#layout-width-and-height) docs or on the [Table](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/components/table) docs.

Answer (score 2):

There is a `<TableContainer />` component which will do what you want... [Docs here](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/components/table/usage#table-container).

```
<TableContainer>
  <Table variant='simple'>
    <TableCaption>Imperial to metric conversion factors</TableCaption>
    <Thead>
      <Tr>
        <Th>To convert</Th>
        <Th>into</Th>
        <Th isNumeric>multiply by</Th>
      </Tr>
    </Thead>
    <Tbody>
      <Tr>
        <Td>inches</Td>
        <Td>millimetres (mm)</Td>
        <Td isNumeric>25.4</Td>
      </Tr>
    </Tbody>
  </Table>
</TableContainer>
```